# WCF and subclasses

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have this ServiceContract

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
void ProcessMessage(Message message);
```

and these objects

```
[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ExtendedMessage : Message
{       
    [DataMember]
    public NameValueCollection AdditionalData { get; set; }
}
```

Will WCF be able to handle if I pass in the subclass to the service method? Or will it drop all extra properties that aren't on the base class?

```
ExtendedMessage msg = new ExtendedMessage();
...
ProcessMessage(msg);
```

Comment: did you managed to get this effect ? I  am fightening with these subjects a long time. Is it possible to have in [OperationContract] HandleData(Base base); and send from SoapUI some drieved objects from Base ? And then if c# will be aware of fact that on base it is hold instance of some subclass - so it invoke proper methods also (polymorphism and so on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you didn't specify ExtendedMessage via the KnownType attribute, you would get an error. Once you've told WCF about ExtendedMessage via KnownType, it will work without losing data.

By the way, you don't need to know the set of possible types at compile time because the KnownType attribute can reference a method that will return the set of possible types at runtime.

Comment: I am fightening with these subjects a long time. Is it possible to have in [OperationContract] HandleData(Base base); and send from SoapUI some drieved objects from Base ? And then if c# will be aware of fact that on base it is hold instance of some subclass - so it invoke proper methods also (polymorphism and so on)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the ServiceKnownType attribute to narrow down the scope of the KnownType attribute. You can apply the ServiceKnownType attribute on a specific operation or on your service contract.